# Ajax Contact Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery/Ajax to send an email. Here is my jQuery/Ajax code:

```
//Ajax Contact Form
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('submit', '.sppb-ajaxt-contact-form', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var $self   = $(this);
        var value   = $(this).serializeArray();
        var request = {
            'option' : 'com_sppagebuilder',
            'task' : 'ajax',
            'addon' : 'ajax_contact',
            'g-recaptcha-response' : $self.find('#g-recaptcha-response').val(),
            'data' : value
        };

        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : request,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $self.find('.fa').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
            },
            success: function (response) {
              var results = $.parseJSON(response);
              var data = $.parseJSON(results.data);
              if(data.status) {
                $self.trigger('reset');
              }
              $self.find('.fa-spin').removeClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
              $self.next('.sppb-ajax-contact-status').html(data.content).fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut(500);;
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

So, when I press the submit button send the email then in browser console I see following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? How can I solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Write `console.log(response)` as the first line in your success callback, and post the console log in your question. Most probably, the console will print html or xml.

Comment: Your response json is not valid